# Problems with update and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Got a problem in a form submitting data. In my situation i'm filling some fields of this table in one form, and the other ones in a second one... this is the code

```
$sqledit=" UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET
`codice`='".$classe."',`datainc`='".$datainc."',
`descrizioneinc`='".$descrizione."',`noteinc`='".$ragione."',
`utente1`='".$utente1."',`utente2`='".$utente2."',
`utente3`='".$utente3."',`utente4`='".$utente4."',
`utente5`='".$utente5."' WHERE numero='$editing'";

mysql_query($sqledit)or die(mysql_error());
```

The problem is that when the other columns (the ones filled by the second form) are filled, it just deletes everything updating the other columns as empty ones. What am i doing wrong?

---

The full code is (deleted host, user and password)

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION["id"]))){
    echo("Devi effettuare l'accesso prima");
            header("Refresh: 5; URL=/Registro/index.php");
    die();
    }
if($_SESSION["id"]=="1"){
    echo("Sezione riservata ai controllori");
            header("Refresh: 5; URL=/Registro/index.php");
    die();
}

$editing=$_SESSION["edit"];

// Create connection
$db_host =;
$db_user = ;
$db_password =;
$db_name =;
$tbl_name="campioni";
mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_password")or die("cannot connect"); 


mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
//metto i valori presi prima in variabili
extract($_POST);
$codice=$_POST['codice'];
$datainc=$_POST['datainc'];
$descrizione=$_POST['descrizione'];
$note=$_POST['note'];
$utente1=$_POST['utente1'];
$utente2=$_POST['utente2'];
$utente3=$_POST['utente3'];
$utente4=$_POST['utente4'];
$utente5=$_POST['utente5'];
//controllo con la tabella sull'sql
$sqledit=" UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `codice`='".$classe."',`datainc`='".$datainc."',`descrizioneinc`='".$descrizione."',`noteinc`='".$ragione."',`utente1`='".$utente1."',`utente2`='".$utente2."',`utente3`='".$utente3."',`utente4`='".$utente4."',`utente5`='".$utente5."' WHERE numero='$editing'";
mysql_query($sqledit)or die(mysql_error());
echo("monitoraggio con numero operazione $editing modificata");
header("Refresh: 5; URL=/Registro/programmazione/control/campione/gestioneCampioneC.php"); ?>
```

Comment: can you post your html code for your form?

Comment: those other columns are not even called in this sql line

Comment: you didnt speciy $editing in your first update query. It is only specified on the second query

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Robert i made a mistake and i just noticed i double pasted the code, my bad. The "editing" value is a session value retrieved in a previous page. The problem is that it DOES update the specified columns, but makes the other ones (which aren't called at all) blank